# Tracking wait statistics per T-SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating an application that tracks some specific performance-related statistics from SQL Server for every query executed on the server. I can get most of the information through [SQL Trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191006.aspx) or more specifically, using the [StatementCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189886.aspx) and [BatchCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176010.aspx) event classes.

Using *SQL Trace* with the above events gives me everything except **wait stats**. I know I can get the wait statistics separately from the two *Dynamic Management Views and Functions* [sys.dm_os_wait_stats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179984.aspx) and [sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188743.aspx).

I need to find a way to somehow club these two information together so that I can determine the wait stats on a per query basis. For example, I need to be able to answer a question like: How long did query X had to wait for an IO or CPU resource before it could begin execution?

I cannot answer this question accurately because SQL Trace does not give me this information. **Is there anyway to obtain wait stats from SQL Server for every statement that is being executed on the server?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on SQL Server 2008 you can use extended events to capture details of the `sqlos.wait_info` event filtered on the spid of interest.

See [SQLSkills: Capturing wait stats for a single operation](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Capturing-wait-stats-for-a-single-operation.aspx) for example code.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Although, it is a bit expensive to use to track every query. Thanks for the quick response!